# BadParcelableException with Google Maps when deploying

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I have Activity that lets a user choose geographical bounds, and returns them through the setResult function:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
.
.

  buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra(RESULT_KEY_MAP_BOUNDS, bounds);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and the calling code is:
.
.
.

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_SELECT_GAME_BOUNDS:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                LatLngBounds bounds = 
                        data.getExtras().getParcelable(SelectGameBoundsActivity.RESULT_KEY_MAP_BOUNDS);
```

When I run through eclipse this works fine, but when trying to create an APK (signed or not) and running on the same device, I get the following error:

> Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds

This happens on the line:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = 
                       data.getExtras().getParcelable(SelectGameBoundsActivity.RESULT_KEY_MAP_BOUNDS);
```

The device is running the latest Google Play Services.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to prevent ProGuard from stripping needed classes.

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { public *; }
```

Add this to your proguard-project.txt file.